# Send a formated list with pushover on python

Tags: python, list, pushover

I'm relatively new to python,

I built a webscraper that gets the top posts of a website and stores them in a list in python like this:

```
T = ["post1","post2","post3,"post4"]
```

To send the push notification with pushover I installed the pushover module that works like this:

```
from pushover import Pushover
po = Pushover("My App Token")
po.user("My User Token")
msg = po.msg("Hello, World!")
po.send(msg)
```

I want to send the list as a message with format, like this:

```
Top Posts:
1. post 1
2. post 2
3. post 3
4. post 4
```

I tried this:

```
msg = po.msg("<b>Top Posts:</b>\n\n1. "+T[0]+"\n"+"2. "+T[1]+"\n"+"3. "+T[2]+"\n"+"4. "+T[3]")
```

The above solution works, however the number of posts will be variable so that's not a viable solution.

What can I do to send the message with the correct formatting knowing that the number of posts in the list will vary from time to time?

Answer (score 0):

Using `str.join` and a comprehension using `enumerate`:

```
msg = po.msg("<b>Top Posts:</b>\n\n" + '\n'.join(f'{n}. s {n}' for n, s in enumerate(T, 1)))
```

Comment: This results in a list like this: **Top Posts:** {n}. s{n}  {n}. s{n}  {n}. s{n}  {n}. s{n}

Comment: I forgot the string formatting. I edited